# Password validation REGEX to disallow whitespaces

Tags: c#, regex, validation

- Password cannot contain white spaces
- must contain at least one numeric char
- must contain 1 capital letter
- and be at least 8 characters in length, max 15

this is what i've got, which does all except WHITE SPACE rule.

```
((?=.*\d)(?=.*[A-Z]).{8,15})
```

what to add for that?

Thanks a lot!
Language: c#, asp:RegularExpressionValidator

Comment: Out of curiosity, why would you disallow spaces?

Comment: Also, why are you capping it to 15 characters? If you have to cap it, do something like 40 characters, at least.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`^((?!.*[\s])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*\d).{8,15})`

Comment: That's pretty much what I wrote, except that this was posted like 12 minutes after and doesn't include explanation, test link and most of all, the 15-character limit is not implemented. Still, if it seems to work perfectly, I hope that's enough :)

Comment: @ccjmne is absolutely write, it does not check 15-character limit.

Comment: @ccjmne is absolutely right, it does not check for 15-character limit.

Try:
^(?!.*[\s])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*\d).{8,15}$
The good practice is to use only that number of characters that is needed, do not disturb users with error messages. Such limitations make usage of automatic utilities for password generation and storage (such as "1Password") impossible.

Answer (score 23):

Just match:

```
^(?!.* )(?=.*\d)(?=.*[A-Z]).{8,15}$
```

How it works:

`.{8,15}` means: *8 to 15 characters*

`(?!.* )` means: *does not contain " "*
`(?=.*\d)` means: *contains at least one digit.*
`(?=.*[A-Z])` means: *contains at least one capital letter*

Comment: Could you break your regex into a multiline comment and add comments on what each part does?

Comment: this did work for 2 whitespaces, but did allow this string for some reason:
as2dadasd asddD

Comment: Try it there: http://regexr.com?37uld, it seems to work for me!
Actually, maybe you just tried it right before I updated it taking in consideration @F.J's comment :)

Answer (score 1):

As an alternative to RegEx, have you considered just basic string parsing? In other words, if you're needing assistance to write the RegEx, what will happen with the maintainability over time?

Simple string parsing is much easier to understand for most of us. Those that follow in our footsteps will have a much easier time understanding the code and adding other requirements as well.

Here's an example using string parsing that is self-documenting, even without the error messages.

```
/// <summary>
/// Determines whether a password is valid.
/// </summary>
/// <param name="password">The password.</param>
/// <returns>A Tuple where Item1 is a boolean (true == valid password; false otherwise).
/// And Item2 is the message validating the password.</returns>
public Tuple<bool, string> IsValidPassword( string password )
{
    if( password.Contains( " " ) )
    {
        return new Tuple<bool, string>( false, "Password cannot contain white spaces." );
    }

    if( !password.Any( char.IsNumber ) )
    {
        return new Tuple<bool, string>( false, "Password must contain at least one numeric char." );
    }

    // perhaps the requirements meant to be 1 or more capital letters?
    // if( !password.Any( char.IsUpper ) )
    if( password.Count( char.IsUpper ) != 1 )
    {
        return new Tuple<bool, string>( false, "Password must contain only 1 capital letter." );
    }

    if( password.Length < 8 )
    {
        return new Tuple<bool, string>( false, "Password is too short; must be at least 8 characters (15 max)." );
    }

    if( password.Length > 15 )
    {
        return new Tuple<bool, string>( false, "Password is too long; must be no more than 15 characters (8 min)." );
    }

    return new Tuple<bool, string>( true, "Password is valid." );
}
```

Comment: This is always a valid alternative, but that note you left: "In other words, if you're needing assistance to write the RegEx, what will happen with the maintainability over time?" makes it absolutely brilliant! I think we've all seen the infamous "RegEx for parsing HTML" post here on SO, and doing simple string validation like the OP needs here with a quick RegEx is just fine; yet, indeed, in their (OP's) case (and surely many other), seems wildly inappropriate, considering that lacking the skill to write it most definitely implies lacking the skill to maintain it! +1 from me 

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
^(?=\D*\d)(?=[^A-Z]*[A-Z])\S{8,15}$
\A(?=\D*\d)(?=[^A-Z]*[A-Z])\S{8,15}\z
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/vlGNIu/1).

*Details*:

- `^` / `\A` - start of string (note `\A` is not compatible with ECMAScript regex flavor)
- `(?=\D*\d)` - at least one digit
- `(?=[^A-Z]*[A-Z])` - at least one uppercase ASCII letter
- `\S{8,15}` - eight to fifteen non-whitespace chars
- `$` / `\z` - until end of string (note that `\z` is not compliant with the ECMAScript regex flavor (e.g. in JavaScript)).

Due to `\S`, there can be no whitespace in the string.

**If you have a more complex pattern and you need to use a lookahead restriction**, add a `(?!\S*\s)` lookahead:

```
^(?!\S*\s)(?=\D*\d)(?=[^A-Z]*[A-Z]).{8,15}$
```